# only allow change line and link. disable all other features with marked

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown, javascript-marked

http://jsfiddle.net/zsvbzwgL/1/

How to only allow change line and link. disable all other features with marked https://github.com/chjj/marked  ?
(like font style, header, list style, image ...)

js

```
marked.setOptions({
  renderer: new marked.Renderer(),
  gfm: false,
  tables: false,
  breaks: false,
  pedantic: false,
  sanitize: true,
  smartLists: true,
  smartypants: false
});

$('.output').on('click', function() {
  var inputVal = $('.textarea').val();

  var decode = marked(inputVal);
  console.log(decode);
});
```

html

```
<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
<div class="output">output</div>
<div class="preview"></div>
```

UPDATE

I tried below two way, both not work with strong ...
    // lexer.rules.strong = { exec: function() {} };
    lexer.rules.strong = /(a^) (a^) (a^)/;
resource https://github.com/chjj/marked/issues/420

```
// d\ne\n\nf\n**c**

var lexer = new marked.Lexer();

lexer.rules.heading = /(a^) (a^) (a^)/;
lexer.rules.strong = /(a^) (a^) (a^)/;  // not work
lexer.rules.em = /(a^) (a^) (a^)/;
lexer.rules.code = /(a^) (a^) (a^)/;

var b = marked.parser(lexer.lex(d));
console.log(b);
>>
<p>d
e</p>
<p>f
<strong>c</strong></p>
```

found this in marked.js,

```
var inline = {
  escape: /^\\([\\`*{}\[\]()#+\-.!_>])/,
  autolink: /^<([^ >]+(@|:\/)[^ >]+)>/,
  url: noop,
  tag: /^<!--[\s\S]*?-->|^<\/?\w+(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*?>/,
  link: /^!?\[(inside)\]\(href\)/,
  reflink: /^!?\[(inside)\]\s*\[([^\]]*)\]/,
  nolink: /^!?\[((?:\[[^\]]*\]|[^\[\]])*)\]/,
  strong: /^__([\s\S]+?)__(?!_)|^\*\*([\s\S]+?)\*\*(?!\*)/,
  em: /^\b_((?:[^_]|__)+?)_\b|^\*((?:\*\*|[\s\S])+?)\*(?!\*)/,
  code: /^(`+)\s*([\s\S]*?[^`])\s*\1(?!`)/,
  br: /^ {2,}\n(?!\s*$)/,
  del: noop,
  text: /^[\s\S]+?(?=[\\<!\[_*`]| {2,}\n|$)/
};
```

but `marked.InlineLexer.rules.strong = /(a^) (a^) (a^)/;` or above way `lexer.rules.strong` both still not work ...

Comment: why tag close? can you leave a comment